# Unlocking FileVault2 macOS

Tags: macos, security, password

we have on our Macs a security policy which actiavates for all users FileVault2 and also but also has a max. attempt to unlock the mac to 10. 
So this is working fine until a user enters more than 10 times a wrong password to login into his Mac. As a result his Account is beeing deactivated.

So we have the Recovery-Key and are able to reset the Password of the user, but even with the new password he only gets over the first login but on the second login (disk decryption) neither his old password as his new password are not beeing accepted. So the user can't login to his account anymore.

Is this working as designed from Apple, or are we doing anything wrong? How its possible to re-active a user account if we have the Recovery-Key?

We are using the current version of Catalina(10.15.x) and on the Mac there is only 1 Admin-Account (no AD connect)

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Any reason you can't wipe it and restore from a backup?

Comment: Sure, that would work but not every time have the users an up-to-date backup.